# Sum fields from ListFields - RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to otherwise solve the problem ...
The need to automatically generate all the columns from the table, the calculation of the sum, the results are updated in the new column? Recognizing the conditions: 1) did not know the names of columns 2) the name of the column to update the known
example table:

[image]

PS
I am an absolute beginner in python programming

```
 import arcpy, os, string
 fc = "D:\\path\\test.shp"



 fieldNameList = []
 fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "*")

    for field in fields:
       if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single", "SmallInteger"):

          fieldNameList.append(field.name)
          fn = "'" + "', '".join(fieldNameList) + "'"
 print(fn)   
 with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [fn]) as cursor:

 for row in cursor:

            row[4] = row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

ERROR - RESULT

```
 >>> 
 'tt', 'ff', 'vv', 'rr', 'update'

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:\path\test.py", line 17, in <module>
   for row in cursor:
 RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently passing a single string, so the cursor is looking for a single field named `'tt', 'ff', 'vv', 'rr', 'update'` instead of individual fields `tt`, `ff`, `vv` (etc.)

Your field name list can be directly used in the UpdateCursor:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldNameList) as cursor:
```

Answer (score 5):

edit: I didn't quite get what you were trying to do, but this should work as a sort of cumulative function.

Untested (there may be some errors with indices):

```
import arcpy, os, string

fc = "D:\\path\\exampless.shp"

fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

fieldNameList = []

for field in fields:
    if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single", "SmallInteger"):
        fieldNameList.append(field.name)
        fn = ("'" + "', '".join(fieldNameList) + "'")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fn) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        myValue = 0
        for i in range(len(fn)):    
            myValue = myValue + row[i]
        row[len(fn)] = myValue
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that. But because of the development model below I need to generate a list of fields names in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...

```
import arcpy, os, string
fc = "D:\\path\\test.shp"

fieldNameList = []
fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "*")

   for field in fields:
      if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single", "SmallInteger"):

         fieldNameList.append(field.name)


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldNameList) as cursor:

   for row in cursor:

        row[4] = row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This will only work for a 5 numeric column table, but if that's what you were going for, great.

Comment: Yes, but with the help of your previous answer phloem, and will work for an indeterminate number of columns :) suma = 0
for i in range(len(fieldNameList)): suma = suma + row[i] row[4] = suma.... thnx very much @phloem